# Spring MVC - how to pass an inheriting type from jsp to controller

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a controller that gets a certain DTO as a parameter:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
   @ResponseBody
   public int processRequest(@RequestBody BaseRequestDTO baseRequestDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {
       ...
   }

}
```

BaseRequestDTO has a field, let's say `String a`.

I have another DTO that extends BaseRequestDTO - MyRequestDTO.
MyRequestDTO also has a field, let's say `String b`.
I'm trying to pass a MyRequestDTO from a jsp form to the controller:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : URL + "/request",
        data : JSON.stringify(eval({
             "a" : "hello",
             "b" : "world"
        })),
        ...
});
```

Now when I try to send the parameters I get this error:

```
Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "b"
```

Because obviously BaseRequestDTO doesn't have that field.

EDIT: The message converters that are defined in the application context:

```
<property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
```

So how can I pass an inheriting type (that has additional fields to the base class) as a parameter to the controller? Does anyone know of a solution to that?

Comment: Can you specify the jacksonMessageConverter you defined in the application context configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is support for this in Jackson , try specifying a property in the support class that holds the concrete type information:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public abstract class BaseRequestDTO {
  ...
}
```

And on the JSON, specify the concrete type:

```
{
  "@class" : "com.yourpackage.MyRequestDTO",
       "a" : "hello",
       "b" : "world"
}
```